# Rate of cooling with unknown starting temp

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

An object with $T_0 = x$ is in a room with fixed temp 30 celcius. After ten minutes the objects temp is negative $10$ celsius and after 10 more minutes it is negative $5$ celsius What was the $T_0$? This is a Newton's law of cooling problem.

I guess since there is no k given that the cooling rate is constant and it warms five degrees per 10 minutes to $T_0 = -15$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a road map for you to follow to the problem's solution.

Newton's law of cooling states that the rate at which a body cools is proportional to the difference between its temperature and the surrounding temperature.  Assuming a very large room, we have the following differential equation:

$$\frac{dT}{dt}=k(T-30)$$

Now, you want to separate the variables and integrate.  This gives:

$$\frac{dT}{T-30}=kdt\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\ln(T-30)=kt+C\quad\Longrightarrow\quad T(t)=Ae^{kt}+30$$

where $A=e^C$.  Now, plug in the two ordered pairs you know, $(10,-10)$ and $(20,-5)$, to obtain a system of two equations in the two variables $A$ and $k$.

$$-10=Ae^{10k}+30\quad\Longrightarrow\quad-40=Ae^{10k}\\-5=Ae^{20k}+30\quad\Longrightarrow\quad-35=Ae^{20k}$$

Solve this system to find the values of your constants.  To find $k$, divide the two equations:

$$\frac{35}{40}=e^{10k}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad k=\frac{1}{10}\ln\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)$$

Use this to find $A$.  Plug $A$ and $k$ back into $T(t)$.  Then just plug in $t=0$ to find the initial temperature.

Comment: Why are you using T and t? THat is incredibly confusing and frustrating to read. What is what?

Comment: @PaulthePirate: In the problem you gave, you specified $T_0$ as the initial temperature.  It is thus natural to use $T$ to denote the variable temperature.  $t$ is a standard variable to denote time.

Comment: I am not getting anything that makes sense out of this. Is it set up right? I am getting $$T = k\frac{t^2}{2} - 30t + c$$

Comment: Does it matter if you use Ae^kt and just e + A?

Comment: Also I have absolutely no idea how to solve that system, it is insanely complex.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, no clue where I went wrong.